# Glympse REST API - Create a New User in an existing Account

Tags: php, rest, glympse

Hi am new to Glympse and would appreciate the help. The majority of our code is written in PHP.

**Scenario:**
I have a browser based application, that each of our users will look to create multiple ticket's (assuming each of the users has installed Glympse on their phones). These tickets will be shared with one or many individuals who may or who may not have Glympse installed (but will need to see where that Glympse User is and when to expect them at the destination).

**Question:**
What is required for me to know to create the "ticket" on behalf of the Glympse User (using the REST API)?  (if possible please share me an example in PHP)

Thanks in advance Larry.